# Cookie или lockalStorage

Tags: javascript, cookie, localstorage, token

Небольшое предисловие.

Если фронтенд и бэкенд приложения. Бэкенд приложение написано на `django` с использованием `rest framework`. Для аутенфикации и авторизации используются токены. Собственно при `login` клиент запрашивает токен, получает его в теле ответа в `json` формате. Данный токен я ставлю в заголовок для запросов на бэк и записываю в `localStorage`, дабы пользователь после закрытия браузера и повторного входа на страницу не вводил пароль. Собственно начитался статей, какой `lockalStorage` ненадежный в плане `XSS` атак, и что лучше бы использовать `cookie`.

Дальше непосредственно вопрос.

Переписывать бэк чтобы токен подставлялся в `cookie` у меня нет никакого желания, да и используются там сторонние библиотеки, так что хотелось бы писать что либо самому. Появилась мысль подставлять `cookie` через `js` на клиенте, так же как с `localStorage`, но опять же теперь есть опасения что токен будет уязвим так же к `XSS` как и с `localStorage`. Вот я и думаю, стоит ли морочиться и пытаться подставить токен в куки на фронте, или оставить в `localStorage`. Или взять себя в руки и переписать бэк, чтобы он токен подставлял в `http` заголовок? Если у вас есть какие то мысли по данному поводу, или статьи, с радостью прочитаю и пообщаюсь на данную тему :)

Comment: А если вы перепишите бек и он будет вставлять в `http` заголовок, то это будут точно те же самые куки. А дайте статью, где написано про `XSS` с `localStorage`.

Comment: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/349164/ @StepanKasyanenko

Comment: https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Comment: Как я понял, особой разницы нету.

Comment: Та я тоже ознакомился с информацией, и ответом на английском stackoverflow, куки файлы тоже уязвимы, ии тут уже стоит вопрос безопасности машины клиента больше. Вообщем идею я расписал в ответе, так что я с тобой согласен)

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно исчерпывающий ответ на мой взгляд был дан на этот же вопрос на английской версии stakoverflow. Краткая суть в том что `localStorage` и `cookie` одинаково уязвимы вредоносными программами и расширениями на стороне клиента. Выбирать нужно исходя из логики, если нужно токен часто слать на бэк, то лучше использовать куки, если нет, то тогда стоит хранить в `localStorage`.
[Оригинальный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404882/cookie-or-local-storage/61405030#61405030)